# Cómo saber cuántos números terminan en 1 en un rango del 1 al 100 en Python?

Tags: python

Cuántos números terminan en 1 en los cuadrados del rango del 1 al 100?

Comment: Añade lo que hayas intentado, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada

Comment: Que tal si lo transforma de entero a cadena y de cadena a lista: n=91; st=str(n); l=list(n);. Ya con la lista podemos saber cual es el ultimo elemento con  la funcion len(l)-1.

Comment: Se me ocurre que utilices una lista que contenga los numeros de ese rango, de esta manera podés utilizar el método .endswith() que tiene python, para saber cual es el que termina en el dígito 1.

Comment: Para saber si un numero `n` termina en 1: `n % 10 == 1 # True si termina en 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurrió esta solución.

```
for number in range(1,101):
    x = number**2
    if(str(x)[-1]) == '1':
        print(f"El número {number}, cuyo cuadrado es {x}, termina en 1")
```

Iniciamos con un for loop y un rango que va desde 1 hasta 100 (coloqué 101 para respetar el "off-by-one" y de esta manera terminar el loop en 100), luego dentro del loop defino una variable [x] la cual contendrá (momentáneamente) el valor del número (cabe destacar que number puede ser de cualquier otro nombre, solo es una manera de nombrar la variable dentro del loop). Procedemos a hacer una comparación convirtiendo el número en un string y comparando su ultimo valor, si esta condición se cumple entonces procedemos a imprimir el número.

Comment: En lugar de `if(str(x)[-1]) == '1':` puedes simplemente decir `if x % 10 == 1:`.